# determining server config

Tags: linux

I have recently set up a Linux server for my college which also hosts the college website and other downloadables. This server is linked to outside world using a leased line connection of 1mbps capacity.
My problem is that the users complain that the downloads from the server are very slow, how can I imporve this?
What things should I be looking at.

My current server config:
Dell vostro260s with 4Gb of ram and i3 processor.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adi, 
This is really a hard question, since there could be thousands of factors:
Here is a list of stuff to look at ...

1. What kind of Webservices you run?
2. How to users download the software?
3. Does it have a lot of Disk I/O ? Does it swap?
4. Did you set up raid?

Try using iotop and powertop to find out what processes cause load on your server...

Answer (score 6):

> This server is linked to outside world using a leased line connection of **1mbps** capacity.
>   My problem is that the users complain that the downloads from the server are very **slow**, how can I imporve this?

I've bolded the relevant words from your question. 1Mbps is slow, therefor downloads from your server will be slow. Get a faster uplink. While you're at it, get a real server.

Answer (score 2):

Try to connect to the server yourself as an outside user and do a wget . See the speed that you are getting.

Do a ping and traceroute from server to other system and other system to server. Take a note of the TTL and round trip value.

Do an iperf to find out the network performance.

Some quick tests that I would rather do.

Answer (score 2):

You've got more than one issue here:

1. "Dell vostro260s" is not a server-grade computer. I don't expect much from it.
2. "leased line of 1Mbps capacity" and most of us have more bandwidth than that on our phones.

This must be a very small college, if it's still only using a T1/E1 for public Internet connectivity.

Anyway, doing anything about either of these two issues is going to require money, and I'm guessing that's probably the one thing they won't give you.

Comment: Agreed - I thought I was an alumni of a small college (~3000 undergrad students), but they're running a 1Gbps circuit now. :)